# Aligning and controlling the space between two figures placed side-by-side and copying them as one

Tags: plotting

I have two figures that I merged side-by-side using Grid. I need to copy them and paste in MS Word to get a high resolution figure. I can copy a single figure by right clicking on it. However I can not copy both figures at once by selecting both of them at once. Another issue is how to customize both plots inside a grid by changing the space between the plots and aligning them. Can anyone please help me?

```
logplot = 
  ListPlot[Table[{i, Log[i]}, {i, 1, 50, 0.5}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Red}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"logplot"}, {0.85, 0.2}], Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
   PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 8}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      FontSize -> 25], 
      Style["y", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 4.5}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> 400, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}];

quadraticplot = 
  ListPlot[Table[{i, 2 + 4*i^2}, {i, 1, 50, 0.5}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Blue}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"quadraticplot"}, {0.75, 0.2}], 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
   PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledDownTriangle]", 12}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      FontSize -> 25], 
      Style["y", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 9000}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> 400, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}];

plot = Grid[{{logplot, quadraticplot}}]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try plot = GraphicsRow[{logplot, quadraticplot}].  Options control spacing & size,  Export to png & import or select & copy as you like.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However I donot understand how to select and copy them? Another point is that when I export in to png and then import again to copy it, then the resolution becomes poor! Has there any alternatives except increasing resolution by using "imageresolution" which increases the file size abnormally.

Comment: You can specify the resolution in `Export`: `Try e.g.:  `Export["d:/tmp/test.png", plot, ImageResolution -> 100]

Comment: With `Grid`, you may change the spacing by inserting `Spacer[nn]` between the graphics, as in: `Grid[{{logplot, Spacer[20], quadraticplot}}]`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do something like this:

```
commonOpts = 
  Sequence[
    PlotRange -> All,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]], 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, 25], Style["y", Black, 25]},
    RotateLabel -> False];

logplot =
  ListPlot[Table[{i, Log[i]}, {i, 1, 50, 1}],
    PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[
        Row[{Style["●", Red, 15], Style[" logplot", "SR", 15]}], 
        {0.85, 0.2}],
    PlotMarkers -> Style["●", 8, Red],
    commonOpts];  
  
quadraticplot =
  ListPlot[Table[{i, 2 + 4 i^2}, {i, 1, 50, 1}],
    AspectRatio -> 1.06 (1/GoldenRatio), 
    PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[
        Row[{Style["▼", Blue, 15], Style[" quadraticplot", "SR", 15]}], 
        {0.77, 0.2}],
    PlotMarkers -> Style["▼", 12, Blue],
    commonOpts];

GraphicsRow[{logplot, quadraticplot}, ImageSize -> 850, Spacings -> 50]
```

[image: plots]

**Notes**

1. I have used `Style` rather than plot style options to localize control over fonts and colors.
2. I had to tweek aspect ratio in `quadraticplot` to make the it the same size as `logplot`.
3. I suppressed the rotation of the y-axis label because I think a single character label shouldn't be rotated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 logplot = 
  ListPlot[Table[{i, Log[i]}, {i, 1, 50, 0.5}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Red}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"logplot"}, {0.85, 0.2}], Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
   PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 8}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      FontSize -> 25], 
     Style["y", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 4.5}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> 400, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}];
 
 quadraticplot = 
  ListPlot[Table[{i, 2 + 4*i^2}, {i, 1, 50, 0.5}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Blue}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"quadraticplot"}, {0.75, 0.2}], 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
   PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledDownTriangle]", 12}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      FontSize -> 25], 
     Style["y", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 9000}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> 400, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15}, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.6596 + x];
 
 plot = Rasterize[
   GraphicsGrid[{{logplot, quadraticplot}}, Spacings -> 20 + y, 
    ImageSize -> {800, 400}], RasterSize -> 1200], {{x, 0}, -0.01, 
  0.01}, {{y, 0}, -10, 10}]
```

It must return the following:

[image]

and play a bit with the `AspectRatio`(x) and `Spacings` (y). The quality you can control by the `RasterSize` option. After you have fixed all parameters, remove Manipulate.

Then export it into the directory, where you have saved your notebook with this code:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "myPlots.png", plot]
```

Then you will be able to import this saved image into Word.

Have fun!

Comment: I see you recommend exporting in png format. Please could you comment on the quality of the resulting plot? Should there be some consideration of resolution?

Comment: You can also use other formats of your liking. I, however, do not recommend to save as epl, since export in this format in Mma works bad.  The resolution (giving you the plot quality) you can control with the options for the `Rasterize` function such as `ImageResolution` and `RasterSize`. Just play with them and see what do you like. My experience is that the quality is enough to be accepted to Phys. Rev. for illustrations to my papers.